Read Excel merged cells strike and non strike data and write to separate files
I have an Excel file where some of the cells got merged and some cells have warp Text with Strike and Non Strike in it.

I want to write the data that non strike records to one Excel and other Strike records to another Excel along with the strike in the cell.
My output1:
col1        |   col2          |  col3    | col4    |col5  |
Sampletext1 | Combines TextC2 |Sample3   | text4   |text5 |
Sampletext2 | Combines TextC2 |Sample3_1 | text4_1 |text5 |
Sampletext2 | Combines TextC2 |Sample3_1 | text4_2 |text5 |

My output2:
col1        |   col2          |  col3    | col4    |col5  |
Sampletext2 | Combines TextC2 |Sample3_1 | text4_3 |text5 |



'text4_3` should be striked out in the output file as well.

I have tried using openpyxl in python

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas as pd

input_file = 'myexecel.xslx'

Workbook = load_workbook(input_file)
for i in Workbook.worksheets:
    if i.sheet_state == "visible":
         sheetname = str(i).replace('<Worksheet "', '').replace('">', '').strip()
         ws = Workbook[sheetname]

         #unmerging the cells
        for merged_cell in ws.merged_cells:
            min_row, min_col, max_row, max_col = merged_cell.min_row, merged_cell.min_col, merged_cell.max_row, merged_cell.max_col
            data = ws.cell(row=min_row, column=min_col).value
            ws.unmerge_cells(start_row=min_row, start_column=min_col, end_row=max_row, end_column=max_col)

            for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=min_row, min_col=min_col, max_row=max_row, max_col=max_col):
                for cell in row:
                    cell.value = data


        data_all = [[cell for cell in row] for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True)]
        df_raw = pd.DataFrame(data_all[1:], columns=headercols)
        df_raw["strike_flag"] = [any(cell.font.strikethrough for cell in row) for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2)]


with the above code I was able to find whether the cell have strike through or not. But not sure how to separate strike through and non strike through records.
In the above code data_all is list of lists. list2 contains data with wrap text along with strikeout and non strikeout text.

Now, I want to extract the index3. In the current example it is 3 but it can be any.
to find the whether RichText exist in the list or not I have tried below code. which is giving an error.

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'

from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.cell.rich_text import TextBlock, CellRichText
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries

for cell in data_all[2]:
        if type(cell.value) == CellRichText:
            for text in cell.value:
                if text.font.strike:
                    print("struck", text)
                else:
                    print("unstruck", text)
        else:
            print("unstruck", cell.value)


Somethings you want to avoid; Workbook = load_workbook(input_file) but Workbook is also imported from Openpyxl. In your loop for i in Workbook.worksheets: , so 'i' is a worksheet. You then assign to the variable 'ws' to the same worksheet if it's visible by stripping the name from the object name. Even it that were necessary i.title would provide the Sheet name. The merge cells are modified while being read.

Since you are not using openpyxl.Workbook there is no need to import it however variables should be preferably lower case. Although it might not cause an issue do not use an import as a variable.
The better variable to use for a workbook is 'wb' or 'workbook' unless you want to specifically identify it.
Modifying the merged cells while looping through the list of merged cells is most likely to return an error. Get the list of merge cells first then loop the list as shown.
The list workbook.worksheets has all the worksheet objects in the workbook so for the line for i in Workbook.worksheets: 'i' is a worksheet. You can check if it's visible if that's necessary then just use i, no need to extract the Sheet name and reassign a new variable using the extracted name.
At the end you can create two dataframes, one where the 'strike_flag' is True and one where it is False.
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.cell.rich_text import TextBlock, CellRichText  # <-- Add import
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries

headercols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']

input_file = 'myexecel.xlsx'
workbook = load_workbook(input_file, rich_text=True)  # <-- Add rich_text

for ws in workbook.worksheets:
    if ws.sheet_state != "visible":
        continue
    else:
        merge_list = [merge for merge in ws.merged_cells.ranges]
        for merged_cell in merge_list:
            min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(merged_cell.coord)
            data = ws.cell(row=min_row, column=min_col).value
            ws.unmerge_cells(start_row=min_row, start_column=min_col, end_row=max_row, end_column=max_col)

            for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=min_row, min_col=min_col, max_row=max_row, max_col=max_col):
                for cell in row:
                    cell.value = data

        data_all = [[cell for cell in row] for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True)]
        df_raw = pd.DataFrame(data_all[1:], columns=headercols)

        ### Check each cell for strikethrough font
        strike_row = []
        for count, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_row=2)):  # Full values needed
            strike_row.append(False)
            for data_cell in row:
                if not strike_row[count] and isinstance(data_cell.value, CellRichText):
                    print(f"Cell {data_cell.coordinate} contains Rich Text")
                    for t_block in data_cell.value:
                        if isinstance(t_block, TextBlock):
                            if t_block.font.strikethrough:
                                print(f"TextBlock '{t_block}' contains strikethrough font")
                                strike_row[count] = True
                                break
                elif data_cell.font.strikethrough:
                    print(f"Cell {data_cell.coordinate} all text is strikethrough")
                    strike_row[count] = True
            print("----------------------------")

        # df_raw["strike_flag"] = [any(cell.font.strikethrough for cell in row) for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2)]
        df_raw = df_raw.assign(strike_flag=strike_row)

        df_strikethrough = df_raw[df_raw.strike_flag]
        df_no_strikethrough = df_raw[~df_raw.strike_flag]

        print(f"Rows with strikethrough\n{df_strikethrough}")
        print(f"Rows without strikethrough\n{df_no_strikethrough}")


Update
I have updated the code to hack a change for checking for cells with full or partial strikethrough font.
The added code essentially replaces the line
# df_raw["strike_flag"] = [any(cell.font.strikethrough for cell in row) for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2)]

As noted you must open the workbook with rich_text=True. This also requires the import of Rich Text components as shown
workbook = load_workbook(input_file, rich_text=True)

and when checking each cell you will need to check the cells full value so values_only= must be False or you won't get the cell values Rich Text details.
Then you can check what cells contain TextBlocks and which of those contain strikethrough font.
Since there is no need to check any other cells in a row after any cell in that row is determined to have strikethrough font the loop breaks out at the first occurrence found.
For an example input Sheet that does contain whole and partial cells with strikethough font

The two dataframes produced are;
Rows with strikethrough
          col1             col2       col3           col4   col5  strike_flag
0  Sampletext1  Combines TextC2  Sample3    Text4          text5         True
1  Sampletext2  Combines TextC2  Sample3    Text4_1        text5         True
4  Sampletext3  Combines TextC2  Sample3_2  Text & strike  text6         True
5  Sampletext3  Combines TextC2  Sample3_3  Text & strike  text6         True


Rows without strikethrough
          col1             col2       col3     col4   col5  strike_flag
2  Sampletext2  Combines TextC2  Sample3_1  Text4_2  text5        False
3  Sampletext2  Combines TextC2  Sample3_1  Text4_3  text5        False


Thank you. But my question is specific to how can I separate the striked out text from the cell.

Also I am not sure why you changed this  if i.sheet_state == "visible":  to  if ws.sheet_state != "visible": why need to check not visible and then proceed and go to else condition when I can directly use as I stated. Any reason for this ?

The dataframe df_strikethrough will have the rows with strikethough cell(s) and df_no_strikethrough is the dataframe with rows without strikethrough. In your code you check if the worksheet is visible, if so then use it, after extracting Sheet name and re-assigning to another varible using the name. In my code the variable is assigned to the worksheet, then it's checked if 'visible'. If it's not visible then move to the worksheet, if it is visible then carry on with the assigned variable.

I want to separate the strikeout text separately. As of now the code will check the whole cell whether any text is straikedout or not. if yes, it will move to strikeout df. But my data have both strikedout and normal text in the same cell. I lacking on this how can I separate this text

If cells contain a combination of strikethrough and non-strikethrough font to detect that in Openpyxl you will need to use Rich Text (load the workbook with this enabled, rich_text=True) and check the text blocks for those that contain strikethrough font.

got an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text'. I am using openpyxl version - 3.0.9.  is rich_text available only in 3.1.3 documentation also refers to this rich text https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rich_text.html , is it my version problem ?

Rich Text support is new in Openpyxl with release 3.1.x You should always use the latest release, which is now 3.1.4.

I have installed the latest version 3.1.4. since my data contains both strikeout and normal data in single cell and I want to separate these data to multiple lines i tried updated code. but getting an error that AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value' when I am looping the values in the list and check whether the value is RichText

What list? The only objecy that has a value is a cell there is no list looping when using cells The code is looping rows and cells. You'll need to do some debugging find out why an apparent cell is a string.
